# How to fetch MediaBox of PDF pages without parsing whole file?

Tags: apache, pdfbox

Is there a way to use Apache PDFBox to read the MediaBox Rectangle of all the pages in a PDF without parsing the entire file? I currently use the following code, which takes a long time for files over 1.5 GB.

```java
// Can I avoid this 'load()' function which tries to parse the entire PDF
pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())

// I can only use TempFile, instead of main memory, as there are restrictions to memory usage in the application.
// get the page media box
pdfDocument.getPage(1).getMediaBox()
```

Comment: A feature as required here is under discussion, cf. [PDFBOX-4512](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4512), but it's not yet implemented.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947276/faster-pdf-page-dimensions-using-pdfbox