# Faster PDF page dimensions using PDFBox?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I am comparing Apache PDFBox (2.0.8) and ITextPDF (5.1.3) on Java.

My use case is to find the dimensions of every page in a PDF.

PDFBox is a lot slower than iText when it comes to this. While iTextPDF seems to have methods to get page's size exclusively, I was not able to find any method which would let PDFBox do the same without reading the page's content.

iText :

```
reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
Rectangle psize = reader.getPageSize(pageNumber);
float width = psize.getWidth();
float height = psize.getHeight();
```

PDFBox :

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(filepath);
PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber);
float height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
```

PDFBox takes almost twice as much time for smaller PDF files compared to iTextPDF. Is there a way to get better performance from PDFBox when we need just the dimensions of the page and not the content?

Comment: Why are you using 2.0.8? That is not the current version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr this code is being written in a corporate scene and changing the version is not an option currently. Also I do not see any major or minor version updates to pdfbox since 2.0.8. (2.0.15 being the latest available)

Comment: See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55944403/1729265): A feature speeding up pdfbox for specific lookups only  is under discussion, cf. [PDFBOX-4512](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4512), but it's not yet implemented.

Comment: There are also speed improvements in version updates, at least one is related to parsing, although I can't tell whether it will apply to you. And certainly security issues fixed. Anyway, if it isn't updated, make sure to cover your back so that corporate won't point at you if things go wrong: https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/3/16410806/equifax-ceo-blame-breach-patch-congress-testimony

Comment: 5.1.3 is not the current version of iText. Version 7.1.6 was released just a few days ago: https://twitter.com/iText/status/1123294538024595456